# rsync with a cron job, jobs are stacked?

Tags: rsync

I would like to rsync a directory with 2 servers.

If I create a cron job each minute on this 2 servers, if a previous rsync job is still running, a new rsync job is created ?

If yes, what is the best practice ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flock in your cron script, which would ensure only one instance is running at a time.

```
/usr/bin/flock -w 0 /path/to/cron.lock rsync -aP /source /dest
```

The `-w 0` flag will make the script fail immediately if another is already running.

Comment: What is the /path/to/cron.lock ?

Comment: @Paul, it can be any file path, where you have read/write access. For example, `/tmp/my-cron-script.lock`. It's used by flock to handle the locking mechanism.